# Simple question regarding dot notation

Tags: linear-algebra

I just have a relatively simple question regarding the following notation. I understand the matrix is being multiplied by it's transpose. However how to interpret the dot and the power? Is it just the resulting matrix multiplied by itself?

Compute $(X^TX) · ^2$

Edit: For reference, this is where the notation appears, in a published machine learning algorithm.

[image]

[link to original paper](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-uER3ivAMaybkxpbzl2UWFudTA/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: It could just mean the element-wise squaring of $(\cdot)$.

Comment: you might want to provide us with some information of where do you see this.

Comment: Original question updated with source

Comment: Again is vague, but it most probably means the element-wise square of the matrix.

Comment: Updated again with link to original source paper if that is any use. Hope that provides more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Page 252, bellow equation (8), clearly states that $(x)\cdot ^2$ stands for the square of each one of the elements of matrix $x$.